# How to manage a facebook page with multiple content creators and one editor that approves posts?

Tags: facebook

A non profit that I am a member of has a public Facebook page that we use to promote our organization. I would like to set it up in a way that would allow many of our members to create content to be posted as the page, but one or two editors would have to approve all posts.

From what I can see, although there are a [few roles available](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410/), Facebook has no functionality for this.

Are there any kind of best practice rules to follow?